# Missing service - mysql: unrecognised service

Tags: 20.04, mysql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running Ubuntu **20.04.6** on WSL, and am having trouble starting mysql-server using the command `sudo service mysql start`, which returns `mysqld: unrecognized service` (the same result with `mysqld`).

For some background, this morning I accidentally upgraded rather than updated my environment, including MySQL to a version my editor (and others I tried) don't currently support (**8.0.35**). I attempted to downgrade to an earlier version, but now no matter what, I'm having issues with getting MySQL up and running again. I've been trawling through posts on here and Stackoverflow, but not had any success as of yet.

Whether it's a permissions problem, or a configuration problem I'm unsure, but please see some of the latest steps I've taken below:

Uninstalled with:
`sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-* mysql-client-core-*`
`sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/log/mysql* /var/run/mysqld`

And to clean up:
`sudo apt-get autoremove sudo apt-get autoclean`
`sudo apt-get update`

Tried installing with both older versions and the latest versions of MySQL:
`sudo apt-get install mysql-server-8.0=8.0.19-0ubuntu5 mysql-client-8.0=8.0.19-0ubuntu5` `sudo sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client`.

After this as mentioned before, when trying `sudo service mysql start` I get `mysqld: unrecognized service`.

In case it just needed registering, I tried registering mysql and mysqld via systemctl, which didn't work, along with creating a custom service in /etc/init.d/ called mysql_custom, also to no avail.

Running `mysql --version` returns:  "Ver 8.0.35 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)", indicating it's at least installed, and running `mysql` and `mysqld` returns the following errors respectfully:

- **mysql**: 2023-12-31T18:12:37.448254Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
  2023-12-31T18:12:37.448300Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.35) starting as process 3855
  2023-12-31T18:12:37.450166Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
  2023-12-31T18:12:37.450172Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
  2023-12-31T18:12:37.450185Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013276] [Server] Failed to set datadir to '/var/lib/mysql/' (OS errno: 13 - Permission denied)
  2023-12-31T18:12:37.450245Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
  2023-12-31T18:12:37.450320Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.35)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
- **mysqld**: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

From here I'm really at a total loss for where to go next, so really hoping somebody on here has been through this or something similar before that can help. If you need any more information, or need me to try running any commands, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is sorted now, it seems that having the packages `php7.4-mysql php8.2-mysql` installed was what caused the issue, although I'm not 100% on if that's the case.

The following solved the issue:

Find all installed packages containing the word "mysql": `apt list --installed | grep mysql`.

Removed all listed packages with the following commands: `sudo apt-get remove --purge your-mysql-packages`, `sudo apt-get autoremove`, `sudo apt-get autoremove`.

Reinstalled mysql and php package: `sudo apt-get install mysql-server php8.2-mysql`.

From here the mysql service was recognised and I was able to set things back up again. Thought I'd share in case anyone else runs into a similar issue with the same setup as me.